# Не работает ide-helper в phpstorm при работе с laravel

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

Работаю с laravel 5.3, использую barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper.Сгенерил .phpstorm.meta.php и _ide_helper.php, но phpstorm все равно помечает классы как undefined. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Классы, которые у вас `undefined` не зависят от `ide-helper`, так что проблема не в нём.

Попробуйте следующие шаги, проверяя состояние после каждого из них.

1. `composer dump-autoload`
2. удалить `vendors`, выполнить `composer install`
3. в phpStorm: `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart.. -> [Invalidate and Restart]`

Каждый раз надо дать время phpStorm'у на индексацию

Answer (score 0):

А ты команды запустил и добавил их в composer ?

```
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan optimize
```