# Laravel, Eloquent - method find() not found in App

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, controller, model

Описываю метод destroy класса TasksController: 
Написал вот такую функцию:

```php
public function destroy ($id) {
        $task = Task::find($id);
        $task->delete();
        return redirect()->route('tasks.index');
    }
```

find() не работает и если навести на него мышь, то пишет, что method find not found in App\Task.

Полный код контроллера:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Task;

class TasksController extends Controller
{
    public function index () {
        $tasks = Task::getAllTasks();
        return view('tasks.index', compact('tasks'));
    }

    public function create () {
        return view('create');
    }

    public function store (Request $request) {

        $task = new Task;
        $task->fill($request->all());
        $task->save();
        return redirect()->route('tasks.index');
    }

    public function destroy ($id) {
        $task = Task::find($id);
        $task->delete();
        return redirect()->route('tasks.index');
    }
}
```

Очень много искал в интернете, но конкретных ответов не нашёл, в том числе на stackoverflow(eng). Пишут, что возможно я подключил что-то не так, но я не вижу ошибки. Направьте пожалуйста в нужную сторону.

Код используемой модели Task:

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['body', 'id'];

    public static function getAllTasks () {
        return self::all();
    }

}
```

Самое странное, что методы fill(), save(), all() работают нормально.

[image: На фото показаны методы при наведении мыши на которые "Method not found in.."]

Вношу дополнения. С момента начала вопроса нашёл такой интересный момент:

```
public function destroy ($id) {
    $task = Task::all()->find($id)->delete();
    return redirect()->route('tasks.index');
}
```

В таком случае find() успешно срабатывает, delete() срабатывает как нужно, но всё же подсвечивает unhandled\exception.

Можно ли при таком подходе считать вопрос закрытым?

Comment: Может стоит показать класс `App\Task` ?

Comment: Необходимо определить главный ключ (primary key), этот метод работает только по нему. Также убедитесь что тип данных, передаваемых этой функции одинаков с определением типа у главного ключа. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37719932/laravel-eloquent-modelfind-doesnt-work)

Comment: Вам бы разобраться с оператором `use` и понятием Пространство имён, а также обратите внимание на регистр. Касательно вопроса: не понятно, куда вы мышью наводите, где возникает данная ошибка?

Comment: У меня выделяется find(), когда навожу мышь конкретно на данный метод, то пишет "method find() not found in App". По поводу primary_key я почитал и возможно я конечно что-то не так понял. Но было написано, что laravel по дефолту использует id как primary_key и определять его отдельно не нужно.

Comment: @DanilZhmak, сделай такие правки https://yadi.sk/d/u6OLfve4dSvx0A

Comment: @МаксимК       сделал правки как на скрине, use App действительно было лишним, но find() всё так же не находит. А у меня с наследованием в моделе всё в порядке?

Comment: Похоже, что ваш вопрос из подобной серии https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/595677/256824

Comment: Разобрался с ide_helper, но нужные мне методы всё равно не обнаруживаются. Сейчас дополню вопрос скриншотом.

Answer (score 0):

Выполнить действия:

1. Проверить, что класс `App\Task` наследует класс `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`
2. Измени `destroy` метод так:

```
public function destroy ($id) {
    /** @var App\Task $task */
    $task = Task::find($id);
    $task->delete();
    // зачем тебе показывать страницы задачи? Ты же ее удалил.
    //return view('tasks.show', compact('task'));
    // лучше сделай редирект на страницу списка задач
    // тут будет работать, если у твоего ресурсного машрута имя `tasks`
    return redirect()->route('tasks.index');
}
```

3. Выполнить команду в консоли `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: Добавил код используемой модели. Насколько я понимаю, то я правильно всё наследую.

2. Выполнил команду, она отработала (создала насколько я понял json файл и папку vendor, я так понимаю это autoload), но это не решило изначальную проблему.

Comment: @Максим К      Я сделал всё, что вы посоветовали, но работать не стало.

Comment: Согласен насчёт redirect(). После того как я разделил find() и delete(), ничего не поменялось, так же не видит find(), перестало видеть delete().

Comment: @DanilZhmak, посмотри, что выводит `dump` https://yadi.sk/d/uTWhRe91Yd2nBA

Comment: Не знаю лазейка это или новая ошибка, но я дошёл до того, что если я нахожу объект не просто используя find($id), а all()->find($id), то в последнем случае find() успешно подсказывается мне Storm'ом и правильно отрабатывает. Дампом $task, я успешно получаю свой объект с нужными полями.

Comment: есть исходники проекта? Очень странное поведение

Answer (score 0):

Проблема кроется в самом фреймворке, он почему-то не обнаруживает некоторые методы.

Решил проблему с помощью _ide_helper. 
Ссылка на источник решения, вопрос менее конкретный(обобщённый), но решение подходит:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29439753/eloquent-orm-code-hinting-in-phpstorm

**Решение: Написать в консоли в корне проекта - "php artisan ide-helper:models"**

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой вариант

```
public function destroy ($id) {
        $task = new Task();
        $result = $task->find($id);
        .....
    }
```

Comment: в методе дестрой создать новый объект :D? Мне же удалить нужно, ахах. Спасибо, я уже нашёл ответ, он ниже :)

Comment: Я думал у вас вопрос про find) Мне казалось напрямую его нельзя вызывать да и под рукой не было сервера с Лорой, что бы потестить) Отметьте там решение которое вам помогло, мб кому пригодится)

Comment: Просто никто не сказал, что laravel не может самостоятельно построить связи в моделях без помощи ide_helper

Answer (score 0):

```php
public function destroy ($id) {
    $task = Task::all()->find($id)->delete();
    return redirect()->route('tasks.index');
}
```

Не корректный подход к удалению. В данном случае вы вытаскиваете ВСЕ задачи, а дальше работаете с коллекцией (то есть ищете первый подходящий по id)

Воспользуйтесь методом `destroy` или `delete` напрямую, чтобы не выбирать эту модель

```php
public function destroy ($id) {
    $task = Task::destroy($id);
    return redirect()->route('tasks.index');
}

// or

public function destroy ($id) {
    $task = Task::where('id',$id)->delete(); // запрос будет работать сразу на удаление, вместо 2-х запросов(find и delete), будет 1 (delete)
    return redirect()->route('tasks.index');
}
```

А по поводу того, что пишет про неизвестный метод - это, как писали выше, проблема ide. Она решается путём подключения всех фасадов, но при этом возникали (лично у меня) другие проблемы. Поэтому не можно не обращать на это внимание. Они прекрасно работают.